# How does Spring detect the correct method name despite an incorrect bean property name defined in configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My apologies if the question is not clear enough, but I will try to explain it below:

I have a class called **CricketCoach.java** that has the following method

```
public class CricketCoach implements Coach {

  private FortuneService fortuneService;

  ......
  ......

  public void setFortunaeService(FortuneService fortuneService) {
    System.out.println("Spring calling the setter method");
    this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
  }

  .......
  .......
}
```

I have the Spring configuration in an **applicationContext.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean
        id = "myFortuneService"
        class = "com.example.basicspring.dependencyinjection.HappyFortuneService">
    </bean>

    <bean
        id = "myCricketCoach"
        class = "com.example.basicspring.dependencyinjection.CricketCoach">
        <property name="fortuneService" ref="myFortuneService"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have the following driver class

```
public class HelloSpringApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Coach theCoach = classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean("myCricketCoach", Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
        classPathXmlApplicationContext.close();
    }

}
```

In the **applicationContext.xml**, I have deliberately given the wrong property name to see what exception Spring throws.

The following exception is thrown by Spring

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCricketCoach' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fortuneService' of bean class [com.example.basicspring.dependencyinjection.CricketCoach]: Bean property 'fortuneService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'fortunaeService'? // Interestingly Spring guesses the correct method name
```

What's interesting here is that Spring guesses the actual method name correctly and suggests this `Did you mean 'fortunaeService'?`

However when I change the name of the method in my **CricketCoach** class from `setFortunaeService` to `setXYZ`

```
public void setXYZ(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        System.out.println("Spring calling the setter method");
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }
```

Spring is no longer able to guess the correct method and shows the following error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myCricketCoach' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fortuneService' of bean class [com.example.basicspring.dependencyinjection.CricketCoach]: Bean property 'fortuneService' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

What I want to know is how Spring was able to guess the property name accurately first time, but wasn't able to do so second time.

What exactly is the logic behind Spring being able to guess the name of the method correctly first time?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

The logic (at least in the version of Spring I am looking at) can be found in class:

org.springframework.beans.PropertyMatches

```
/**
 * Generate possible property alternatives for the given property and
 * class. Internally uses the <code>getStringDistance</code> method, which
 * in turn uses the Levenshtein algorithm to determine the distance between
 * two Strings.
 * @param propertyDescriptors the JavaBeans property descriptors to search
 * @param maxDistance the maximum distance to accept
 */
private String[] calculateMatches(PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors, 
       int maxDistance) {

    List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : propertyDescriptors) {
        if (pd.getWriteMethod() != null) {
            String possibleAlternative = pd.getName();
            if (calculateStringDistance(this.propertyName, possibleAlternative) 
                      <= maxDistance) {
                candidates.add(possibleAlternative);
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(candidates);
    return StringUtils.toStringArray(candidates);
}
```

As the comments note, alternatives are caclulated using the following algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

and setXyz will be too distant to be considered.